# How to add a margin top to a bitmap?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-bitmap, android-gravity

This is the drawable file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">
  <item>
    <color android:color="#ffffffff"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <bitmap android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_screen"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

I want the bitmap to have 20px margin-top, I didn't find how to set margin-top to bitmaps element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [**`android:top`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource).

> The top offset in pixels.

```
    <item
        android:top="20dp">
         <bitmap android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
         android:src="@drawable/splash_screen"/>

    </item>
```